# Autoreplacing words to links

Tags: javascript

I'm not the best in coding, but I have to create something to autoreplace tags with links.

Each my product has part:

```
<p class="tag-field">Tags: word1, word2,... wordLAST</p>
```

I need a solution to replace each word with coresponding link for example word1 with:

```
<a href="https://mypage/word1">word1</a>
```

Could You help me?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey this seems to be working

```js
const field = document.getElementById('tag-field');
const words = field.innerHTML.split(',');
var linkedWords = [];
words.forEach(word => {
  //using trim to take care of whitespaces
  word = word.trim();
  linkedWords.push(`<a href='https://mypage/${word}'>${word}</a>`);
});
field.innerHTML = linkedWords;
```

```html
<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <div>
    <p id='tag-field'>
      word1,word2,word3
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the taglist like so

```
let tags = [];
let tagsElem = document.getElementsByClassName("tag-field")[0];  //get the element containing the tags

if (tagsElem) {
  let tagString = tagsElem.innerText;  //this is the list of tags
  if (tagString.length > 6) tags = tagString.substr(6)  //remove "Tags: " from string
    .split(',')  //split the list by ","
    .map(x => x.trim());  //remove leading and trailing spaces of tags
}
```

So if there is an according element which has the appropriate content (add more checks if needed!) you get a list of tags. Then you can create a link for each of them

```
let parent = ... //get some element where you want to add your links
for (let tag of tags) {
   let a = document.createElement("a");
   a.href = `https://yoursite.com/${tag}`
   a.innerText = tag; //or whatever text you want to show for your link
   parent.appendChild(a);
}
```